# What is the daisy-bkt bucket in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I just noticed that a new bucket has been created in my google cloud storage project. I have no idea why it is there or who created it. And, it takes up 2.6 GB!

If I execute `gsutil du -h gs://PROJECT_NAME-daisy-bkt-us-central1`

I get:

```
5.72 KiB     gs://PROJECT_NAME-daisy-bkt-us-central1/gce-image-import-2021-05-14T10:18:42Z-prqjy/daisy-inflate-20210514-10:18:44-7y6j3/logs/daisy.log
111.72 KiB   gs://PROJECT_NAME-daisy-bkt-us-central1/gce-image-import-2021-05-14T10:18:42Z-prqjy/daisy-inflate-20210514-10:18:44-7y6j3/logs/inst-importer-inflate-7y6j3-serial-port1.log
117.44 KiB   gs://PROJECT_NAME-daisy-bkt-us-central1/gce-image-import-2021-05-14T10:18:42Z-prqjy/daisy-inflate-20210514-10:18:44-7y6j3/logs/
10.51 KiB    gs://PROJECT_NAME-daisy-bkt-us-central1/gce-image-import-2021-05-14T10:18:42Z-prqjy/daisy-inflate-20210514-10:18:44-7y6j3/sources/import_image.sh
2.58 GiB     gs://PROJECT_NAME-daisy-bkt-us-central1/gce-image-import-2021-05-14T10:18:42Z-prqjy/daisy-inflate-20210514-10:18:44-7y6j3/sources/source_disk_file
2.58 GiB     gs://PROJECT_NAME-daisy-bkt-us-central1/gce-image-import-2021-05-14T10:18:42Z-prqjy/daisy-inflate-20210514-10:18:44-7y6j3/sources/
2.58 GiB     gs://PROJECT_NAME-daisy-bkt-us-central1/gce-image-import-2021-05-14T10:18:42Z-prqjy/daisy-inflate-20210514-10:18:44-7y6j3/
2.58 GiB     gs://PROJECT_NAME-daisy-bkt-us-central1/gce-image-import-2021-05-14T10:18:42Z-prqjy/
```

I can see that it was created on May 14 2021.

Does anyone know what it is? And, is it safe to delete?

Comment: Did you import a virtual machine image?

Comment: Not that I can remember. Or even know how to do. And I'm the only developer. This was done roughly in the same time period when I implemented a PubSub firebase cloud function to monitor billing increases, but I don't know why that would have included a virtual machine...

Comment: I just went through the logs found in the bucket, and I saw a reference to 'meilisearch', and I kinda rememeber considering it for a search option. I went with AlgoliaSearch instead. So, it must have something to do with that... Sorry, I should have found this before. Still unsure how this came about. I must have done it without knowing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out myself. Turns out, like John Hanley kindly pointed out, that I had imported a virtual machine. And I guess this bucket was created as part of that import.

The reason I had imported it was trying to set up Meilisearch on a VM following their guide here: https://docs.meilisearch.com/create/how_to/gcp.html

I ended up deleting the VM since I didn't use Meilisearch, but I guess this bucket was left behind.

I'm going to delete it since I don't even have the VM left, and can't think of a reason why I'd need that bucket. (if this turns out to be a terrible idea and everything breaks, I'll be sure to come back here and post about it)

Answer (score 0):

This bucket appears when you import a VM image. To explain what Daisy is, it is an open source project that implements image management workflows. This tool basically runs the import workflow within GCE.

If the bucket is deleted mid import there will be an issue as it is currently used. It is safe to delete once the import process is completed, just make sure that you are not using the VM anymore.

For further explanation or details you check out this link.
https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/compute-image-tools/daisy.html